# Storing information glitch

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am trying to get this form to send info to MySQL DB. The DB always issues an error. I have been trying to work out what the issue is and I do not seem to be able to find the problem. As I am a relative newbie that could have quite a lot to do with the problem.  The code for the page to send info to DB is

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once('commoninclude.php');
session_start();
///session check
   if(!(isset($_SESSION["admin"]) && $_SESSION["admin"] != ""))
    {
     header("Location:index.php");
    }
   $smarty = new Smarty();
  

   if((isset($_SESSION['campaignid'])) && ($_SESSION['campaignid']!=""))
    $newcampid=$_SESSION['campaignid'];
   else
   $newcampid="";

 if( (isset($_SESSION['campid']) )&& ($_SESSION['campid']!=""))
 {
    $rowcamp= Show_Campaign($_SESSION['campid']);
}

 if((isset($_REQUEST['view']))&&  ($_REQUEST['view']!=""))
    {  
        $excampid=$rowcamp[0];
        $mesid=Update_Campaign_Messages($excampid);
        $setingid=Update_Campaign_Settings($excampid);
        $subscriberid=Update_Campaign_Subscribers($excampid);
        $_SESSION['showcampid']="";
        unset($_SESSION['showcampid']);
        $_SESSION['editcamp']="no";
    }
    else if( (isset($_SESSION['edit']))&&  ($_SESSION['edit']!=""))
    {   
        $_SESSION['showcampid']="";
        unset($_SESSION['showcampid']);
        $_SESSION['editcampaignid']=$rowcamp[0];
        $_SESSION['editcampaignname']=$rowcamp[1];
        $_SESSION['editcamp']="yes";
    }   
        
   if( (isset($_SESSION['editcampaignid']))  && ($_SESSION['editcampaignid']!=""))
    {
        $newcampid=$_SESSION['editcampaignid'];
        $_SESSION['campaignid']=$newcampid;
        
    }   
    else if( (isset($_SESSION['campaignid'])) && ($_SESSION['campaignid']!=""))
    {
        $newcampid=$_SESSION['campaignid'];
    }
            
////coding for save settings    
    if(isset($_POST['txtsetfromname']))
    {
    $var=$_POST['auto_remove'];
    $count_list=count($var);
    if($count_list!=0)
    {
    $auto_remove=implode(",", $var);
    }
    else
    {
    $auto_remove="";
    }
        $setid= Update_Setting($_POST['txtsetfromname'],$_POST['txtsetfromemail'],$_POST['txtredirect'],
        $_POST['txtredirect_unsubscribe'],$_POST['chkaddsublink'],$_POST['chkreporttoadmin'],
        $_POST['settingid'],$_POST['txtadminmail'],$_POST['chkrssfeed'],$_POST['optintype'],
        $_POST['dbl_opt_red_url'],$_POST['dbl_opt_subject'],$_POST['dbl_opt_matter'],
        $_POST['chkstopmail'],$_POST['rss_subs'],$_POST['max_mail_limit'],
        $_POST['next_camp_name'],$auto_remove,$_POST['require_pop'],$_POST['pop_server'],
        $_POST['pop_emailid'],$_POST['pop_password'],$_POST['subs_thru_mail'],$_POST['subs_emailid'],
        $_POST['subs_subject'],$_POST['unsubs_thru_mail'],$_POST['unsubs_emailid'],$_POST['unsubs_subject'],$_POST['msg_formate'],
        $_POST['hd_block_ip_list'],$_POST['hd_block_semail_list'],$_POST['hd_block_domain_list'],
        $_POST['hd_block_pemail_list'],
        $_POST['field_last_name'],$_POST['blocked_redirect_url'],$_POST['call_api'],$_POST['product_number'],
        $_POST['allow_rewards'],$_POST['number_signup'],$_POST['download_link'],
        $_POST['referral_email_subject'],$_POST['referral_url_email'],
        $_POST['reward_email_subject'],$_POST['reward_email'],
        $_POST['allow_multiple_rewards'],$_POST['download_link_2'],$_POST['download_link_3'],
        $_POST['allow_vistors_reward'],$_POST['multiple_vistors_reward'],
        $_POST['numbers_of_visits'],$_POST['visit_reward1'],$_POST['visit_reward2'],
        $_POST['visit_reward3'],$_POST['vistors_email_subject'],$_POST['vistors_reward_email']
        );  
    else    
       
      $setid=Save_Settings($_POST['txtsetfromname'],$_POST['txtsetfromemail'],$_POST['txtredirect'],
      $_POST['txtredirect_unsubscribe'],$_POST['chkaddsublink'],$_POST['chkreporttoadmin'],
      $_POST['txtadminmail'],$_POST['chkrssfeed'],$_POST['optintype'],$_POST['dbl_opt_red_url'],
      $_POST['dbl_opt_subject'],$_POST['dbl_opt_matter'],$_POST['chkstopmail'],
      $_POST['rss_subs'],$_POST['max_mail_limit'], $_POST['next_camp_name'],$auto_remove,
      $_POST['require_pop'],$_POST['pop_server'], $_POST['pop_emailid'],
      $_POST['pop_password'],$_POST['subs_thru_mail'],$_POST['subs_emailid'],
      $_POST['subs_subject'],$_POST['unsubs_thru_mail'],$_POST['unsubs_emailid'],$_POST['unsubs_subject'],$_POST['msg_formate'],
      $_POST['hd_block_ip_list'],$_POST['hd_block_semail_list'],$_POST['hd_block_domain_list'],
      $_POST['hd_block_pemail_list'],$_POST['field_last_name'],$_POST['blocked_redirect_url'],$_POST['call_api'],$_POST['product_number'],
      $_POST['allow_rewards'],$_POST['number_signup'],$_POST['download_link'],
      $_POST['referral_email_subject'],$_POST['referral_url_email'],
      $_POST['reward_email_subject'],$_POST['reward_email'],
      $_POST['allow_multiple_rewards'],$_POST['download_link_2'],$_POST['download_link_3'],
      $_POST['allow_vistors_reward'],$_POST['multiple_vistors_reward'],
      $_POST['numbers_of_visits'],$_POST['visit_reward1'],$_POST['visit_reward2'],
      $_POST['visit_reward3'],$_POST['vistors_email_subject'],$_POST['vistors_reward_email']
      );      if(isset($_POST['settingid']) && ($_POST['settingid']!=""))
        
 
  }

  require_once('show.all.php');
    if((isset($_REQUEST['savesetting'])) && ($_REQUEST['savesetting']!="") )
    {
        $smarty->assign("saved","true");
    }   
    else
    {
        $smarty->assign("saved", "");
    }   
   
   
  
  
    $newcampid=$_SESSION['campaignid'];
    $camp_name=getNameByCamnpId($_SESSION['campid']);
    $custom_fields=GetAllCustomFields($_SESSION['campid']);
    $tracking_links=GetAllTracking_links($_SESSION['campid']);
    $All_group=GetAllGroupName($_SESSION['campid']);
    $campaign_list=Show_Selected_Campaign($_SESSION['campid']);

    $smarty->assign("camp_name",$camp_name);
    $smarty->assign("newcampid",$newcampid);
    $smarty->assign("custom_fields",$custom_fields);
    $smarty->assign("tracking_links",$tracking_links);
    $smarty->assign("All_group",$All_group);
    $smarty->assign("campaign_list",$campaign_list);
    
    
    require_once('../include/menu.php');
    $smarty->assign("url","campaign.php");
    $smarty->assign("setting","settings.php?sec=savesetting");
    $smarty->assign("message","message.php");
    $smarty->assign("date","message.php");
    $smarty->assign("subscriber","subscribers.php");
    $smarty->display("settings.main.tpl.html");
        
//      $RedirectTo = "showcamp.php?campid=".$newcampid;
//      if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) 
//      {
//        $RedirectTo .= (strpos($RedirectTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
//       $RedirectTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
    //}
  //sheader(sprintf("Location: %s", $RedirectTo));

require_once('richtext.php');

?>
```

The error code is as follows.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, ' at line 57 SQL query : Insert into rss_settings (`campid`, `fromname`, `fromurl`, `redirecttourl`, `redirect_url_after_unsubscribe`, `setunsubscribelink`, `reporttoadmin`, `admin_email`, `display_rss`, `opt_in_type`, `dbl_opt_redirect`, `dbl_opt_sub`, `dbl_opt_body`, `stop_mail`, `rss_subs`, `max_mail_limit`, `next_camp_name`, `auto_remove`, `require_pop`, `pop_server`, `pop_emailid`, `pop_password`, `subs_thru_mail`, `subs_emailid`, `subs_subject`, `unsubs_thru_mail`, `unsubs_emailid`,`unsubs_subject`,`msg_formate`,`block_ip_list`,`block_semail_list`,`block_domain_list`,`block_pemail_list`,`field_last_name`,`blocked_redirect_url`,`call_api`,`product_number`,`allow_rewards`,`number_signup`,`download_link`,`referral_email_subject`,`referral_url_email`,`reward_email_subject`,`reward_email`, `allow_vistors_reward`,`multiple_vistors_reward`,`numbers_of_visits`,`visit_reward1`,`visit_reward2`,`visit_reward3`,`vistors_email_subject`,`vistors_reward_email`) VALUES(1, 'somewhere', 'somewhere@somewhere.com', 'https://somewhere.com/emails/thanks.php', 'https://somewhere.com/emails/unsubscribe.php', NULL, NULL, 'facebookleads@somewhere.com', NULL, 'Double', 'https://somewhere.com/lead_page/index.php', 'Your Download is Ready', '#Name# Please download your book from the link below. #VerifyLink# Regards somebody', NULL, NULL, 0, '1st Sale', NULL, 'N', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'text', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'on', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'No', 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL )

I am quite new to this and still learning so any pointers would be welcomed.

Comment: Side note: Formatting could use some improvement. Maybe use more frequent newlines to separate `$_POST...,` params?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma between the 8th and 9th column from the end.

```
   \/                  
NULL NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL )
   /\
```

Comment: But that is what is being returned whe submit is pressed so I can not add a comma can I?

Comment: Surely the comma is missing from *your* code in the `Save_Settings` function @Alexmark

Comment: Joe you are a star. I was not thinking right and was not looking at the save settings as Joni pointed out.